# divide and conquer - finding the median for an array

Tags: algorithm, proof, divide-and-conquer

Say we have an array of size 2n of all unique elements.

Assume we split the array into 2 arrays of size n, and we have a special constant time lookup to find the kth smallest element for that particular array if 1 <= k <= n, so for [4 5 6], k=2 returns 5.

Then what is the Θ(log(n)) algorithm for finding the median? Median is defined as the nth lowest element between the 2 arrays. If array was [1 2 3 4 5 6], median would typically be (3+4)/2, but we just choose the smaller one which is 3. 
My attempt ie:

```
2n = 6  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
n = 3   [1 2 3] [4 5 6] (not necessarily sorted, but we have the constant time lookup, so sorting is irrelevant)
Step 1) use lookup where k = n to find the kth smallest element for each array
[1 2 3] [4 5 6]
     ^       ^ (if k = 3, we get 3 for the first array, 6 for the second array)
Step 2) compare the 2 values we got and choose the smaller one. 3 is the median where median is defined as the nth lowest element between the 2 arrays.
```

First off, is this the correct algorithm for Θ(log(n)) time? Secondly, what would the proof correctness (that it finds the median) look like? I believe it would be through induction.

Comment: `Assume [...] we have a special constant time lookup to find the kth smallest element for that particular array if 1 <= k <= n` That sounds like a big assumption to me...

Comment: If you split your array into [1 2 6] [3 4 5], then your algorithm returns 5. so it cannot be correct.

Comment: Oh, you're right, @HugoRune.

Answer (score -1):

Selection (of which median computation is a special case) cannot be solved in O(log n) time.  You can solve it in O(n) time using an algorithm such as [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: If you use the [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to choose the pivots, you get O(n) with a largish constant in front. That's because the median of medians algorithm is guaranteed to return a value between the 30th and 70th percentiles, and therefore the worst case performance is T(n) = O(n) + T(n/5) + T(0.7n) = O(n).